# JavaScript Class method not updating css style

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I am trying to update some css using a js class(part of what the said class is doing among other things)
The code below is a rough Idea of what am trying to do and where the error comes in

```
//Js Code
let button =document.querySelector('button')
let eventA = new Someclass(button);
   button.addEventListener('click, function(){ eventA.changecss('"green"' })

//class inside the js
class Someclass {
   constructor(item){
   this.item = item
    }

    changecss(new_style){   
       this.item.style.color = new_style
         }
  }
```

So, everything works okay but under the

```
changecss(new_style)
```

I am unable to change css values.I can however get the values of the target item(button in my case)

```
this.item.style
```

returns css declaration correctly
But

```
this.item.style.color = 'red'
```

Does not work and returns a `.color is not defined`

Comment: Can you post something closer to the actual code? What you've posted now is a syntax error. With the code you did post (minus the syntax error), I don't see how you'd get the error you mentioned. Maybe the thing that's going wrong is due to something that you didn't post.

Comment: The actual class is large and complex..other methods in it work okay but the same exact method for changing css as above is not working.. Could you share where the syntax error is comming from in the code above?

Comment: `button.addEventListener('click, function(){ eventA.changecss('"green"' })` should be `button.addEventListener('click', function() { eventA.changecss('green'); })`

Comment: Whoa.. didn't notice that..Thanks.However  the main issue comes in assigning the new css properties..even if i try any other property say this.item.style.width = "100px " inside the class method its still failing

Comment: @ERICNDERITU is it possible that you do not wait for page load before selecting button? because this worked quite well for me. [sample](https://js.do/code/thisworksquitewell)

Comment: Works for me too: https://codepen.io/dullreferenceexception/pen/WNQKwEw. Again, the problem is likely outside of what you posted here.

Comment: It worked finally.